# MPAndroidChart - How to align seekbar with x-axis skipping extra padding?

Tags: android, charts, seekbar, mpandroidchart

I'm working with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I'm really enjoying it since it's really well done.

But I've got a problem that I haven't been able to resolve in a few hours. I've got a seekbar under the three charts (as you can see from the screenshots below) and I'd like to align it with the X-axis, skipping the space occupied by the Y-axis' labels on the left and the padding that gets added on the right.

Have you got any suggestion on how to achieve my goal? Is there a way of knowing the labels' width and the charts' extra-padding? Or, better, can I get the X-axis width?

Thanks in advance! Bye!

[image: left padding]
[image: right padding]

Answer (score 3):

Update to the latest version of the library if you have not already.
Then, just **remove all offsets** from the chart. It's in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport).

Call:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

This will remove all padding / margin / offset from the chart, making the actual content of the chart (the data) being the next thing to your screen edge.